# mysql groupconcat and a condition

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I need to get the bug_id s which satisfy the condition `timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:01:00"`

I created the query with this

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
DISTINCT 
bug_id 
from bugs 
where 
timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:01:00" 
SEPARATOR ' '
)
```

Please help as I am getting error on this query:

```
select sum(IF(priority="P3",1,0)) P3count,
SUM(IF(priority="P2",1,0)) P2count,
sum(IF(timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:01:00",1,0)) exeeded,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bug_id from bugs where priority="P2") 
from bugs 
where  bugs.product_id=237 
and bugs.resolution='FIXED' 
and bugs.creation_ts >='2013-06-14 09:00:00' 
and bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-16 08:59:59' 
and bug_status="RESOLVED";
```

Throwing error:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to usenear 'from bugs where priority="P2") from bugs where  bugs.product_id=237 and bugs.res' at line 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select sum(IF(priority="P3",1,0)) P3count, SUM(IF(priority="P2",1,0)) P2count, sum(IF(timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:01:00",1,0)) exeeded, (select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bug_id) from bugs where priority="P2") as bugids from bugs where bugs.product_id=237 and bugs.resolution='FIXED' and bugs.creation_ts >='2013-06-14 09:00:00' and bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-16 08:59:59' and bug_status="RESOLVED";

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, but the query is so complex. I am writing the same condition inside and outside the nested query.

```
select
sum(IF(priority="P3",1,0)) P3count, 
SUM(IF(priority="P2",1,0)) P2count, 
sum(IF(timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:01:00",1,0)) exeeded, 
(select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bug_id) from bugs 
  where timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:01:00" 
  and bugs.product_id=237 
  and bugs.resolution='FIXED' 
  and bugs.creation_ts >='2013-06-14 09:00:00' 
  and bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-16 08:59:59' 
  and bug_status="RESOLVED") as exeededbugids 
 from bugs 
 where bugs.product_id=237  
 and bugs.resolution='FIXED' 
 and bugs.creation_ts >='2013-06-14 09:00:00'  
 and bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-16 08:59:59'  
 and bug_status="RESOLVED";
```

```
+---------+---------+---------+-----------------+
| P3count | P2count | exeeded | exeededbugids   |
+---------+---------+---------+-----------------+
|       5 |       6 |       2 | 3743304,3743305 |
+---------+---------+---------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
 sum(IF(priority="P3",1,0)) P3count, 
 SUM(IF(priority="P2",1,0)) P2count, 
 sum(IF(timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:01:00",1,0)) exeeded,
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bug_id) as exeededbugids 
from bugs 
 where timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:01:00"
 and bugs.product_id=237  
 and bugs.resolution='FIXED' 
 and bugs.creation_ts >='2013-06-14 09:00:00'  
 and bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-16 08:59:59'  
 and bug_status="RESOLVED";
```